# linked server update issue

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-4, linked-server

I'm using entity framework 4 data model entity to connect  to sql server 2008 synonym:

```
use WTT
CREATE SYNONYM [dbo].[Departments] FOR  PLISTI...nodalas
```

nodalas is linked server's table. Now i can select from this table but cannot make any update operation. I'm getting "The operation could not be performed because OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "PLISTI" was unable to begin a distributed transaction" error. During insert operation sql server profiler shows me this query:

```
exec sp_executesql N'insert [dbo].[Departments]([Nodala_id])
values (@0)
',N'@0 nvarchar(max) ',@0=N'wwwwdddd'
```

When i'm running this query in sql server management studio it work's. But in entity framework NO. Why?

Comment: Do you have a DB server and a web server or both of them are located in a same machine? If DB and Web are located on different computers you should configure msdtc on both of them.

Comment: DB server and web server located in the same machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configure [Microsoft Distributed Transaction Coordinator](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc759136%28WS.10%29.aspx) for the local and linked server. Instructions for Windows Server [2003](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/817064) and [2008](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753620%28WS.10%29.aspx).

Comment: Follow the steps in this article to troubleshoot http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2083/troubleshooting-sql-server-distributed-transactions-part-1-of-2/